# How to find all cells containing a formula that contains a specific constant?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

let me show you an example of what I'm looking for. I have some constants defined in my excel workbook.
For example two contants mght be
Diesel_density = 0,84
Total_volume = 550

In another sheet I have some cells containing formulas like

A1=Diesel_density*100

A2=Diesel_density*Total_volume/100

I am looking for a formula that allows me to set up a cell in which I can type a string or value and it highlights (with conditional formatting or similar functions) all the cells that have that string/value in their formula. Please note that I am not looking to verify the presence of the string in the cell value, as all cell values will be numbers, but in the cell formula.

In the example I made, if I was to type "Total" in the "search cell", I'd like it to highlight the A2 cell only.

The purpose of this is to be able to check which cells values will be affected if one of the constants set in a specific sheet will be changed. For example, if Total_volume is changed to 600, alot of cells will contain that constant, and it is not possible to check it one by one, so I need an automatic function for this task.

Note that the Trace dependent function doesn't work in this case, since the cells using the named constants are in a different sheet that the one where all constants are defined.

Basically I need something that does what the simple Find tool already does since it looks for the text to search also in the formulas, but I need something that highlights all cells containing that string in their formula at once, without having to "find next" and look for each one.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `ISNUMBER(FIND([your string],FORMULATEXT(Range you want to check)))` ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is already available as a feature in Excel - called "[Trace Dependents or Trace Precedents](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-a59bef2b-3701-46bf-8ff1-d3518771d507)"

Steps:

1. Select the cell you want to check for references
2. got to Formula's tab in the Ribbon
3. Click "Trace Dependents" button

Additional Resources:

- [Official Documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-the-relationships-between-formulas-and-cells-a59bef2b-3701-46bf-8ff1-d3518771d507)
- [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_itFoym6NQo)
- [External Article](https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/excel/study/trace-dependents/)

Comment: Hi Gangula and thanks for the answer. I am aware of the trace dependent function, but it doesn't work in my case, since the cells that contain that constant are in different sheets and they cannot be displayed at once. If I press the Trace dependent button, not only displays a short arrow leading to the symbol of a table, but no sign of highlight is visible in the sheet where the constant is actually used.